# Accessing Sharepoint using Python

Tags: python, python-3.7, sharepoint-api, sharepoint-2019

Need your help in accessing sharepoint list in my org. below is the code i'm using.
After logging into sharepoint i wanted to access list and modify few fields to it.

```
from shareplum import Site
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
from shareplum.site import Version

cred = HttpNtlmAuth('some_user_email_id', 'password')


site = Site('https://findout.america.net',version=Version.v2019 , auth= cred)
```

i had used authorize cookies as well, it didn't work.

Error:

> shareplum.errors.ShareplumRequestError: Shareplum HTTP Post Failed : HTTPSConnectionPool ***some text ** _vti_bin/Sites.asmx (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)')))

Tools Being used:
Sharepoint On-Premise Version 2019
Python 3.7 in pycharm IDE

Let me know if anything needs clarification.

Regards,

Comment: This is an SSL error saying that the site's SSL certificate is invalid. This may be because a self-signed certificate was used (which can't be verified by definition) or that the machine you use hasn't joined the domain. On an Active Directory domain the domain is a trusted certificate authority so all domain computers trust certificates issued by the domain.

Comment: What OS are you using? If the code runs on Windows, why are use explicit credentials to login? Windows Authentication means you *don't* need to specify credentials. The connection is made using the current user's account. Since the local machine already knows who the current user is there's no need to reauthenticate (and risk losing the stored password). The domain machines exchange authentication tokens, not passwords

Comment: i'm using Windows 10 Enterprise 64 bit OS. Not sure on how to go about it, just used codes posted here.